# Excel Destination [140]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT"

Tags: excel, ssis, nvarchar, ntext

I have SSIS package that takes data from OLE DB source and loads to an Excel. The Field in the SQL table is nvarchar(max) and the data conversion I put for it when it goes into the excel is DT NTEXT. But I still keep getting this error. I would appreciate any help on this.

Excel Destination [140]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Value_Comments" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
Error: 0xC0202025 at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination [140]: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Excel Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `DT_WSTR` with an `nvarchar(max)` column. `DT_NTEXT` is for the now-deprecated `ntext` data type. If you need to be able to output unicode character data longer than 4000 characters that `DT_WSTR` is limited to (IIRC) then I would cast the column to an `ntext` column in your query, but I believe you will lose some SSIS functionality when you do that.

See the SSIS data types documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types).